# I installed Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS successfully. but get issue with WiFi adopter not found

Tags: 18.04, wireless, bluetooth

I have a Hp omen  16-c0140ax. This system has a AMD ryzen processor and AMD Radeon RX6600m graphics. I installed Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS successfully. The issue is wifi adopter not found.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for desh: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: 5c:60:ba:c0:07:fb
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:54 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf04000-fcf04fff memory:fcf00000-fcf03fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fce00000-fcefffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp8s0f4u1
       serial: da:d5:2a:eb:f1:d8
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.97.141 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your system is *way* too new for that version of Ubuntu. 18.04 will also be out of support in just a few days. It would be better to install 22.04 or 23.04 to get the most from your hardware.

Comment: Just FYI:  The 18.04 tells you it was the 2018-April release of Ubuntu given the *year.month* format of Ubuntu releases (2000 being subtracted from the year). As 18.04 had 5 years of *standard* support from 2018-April; it's nearly all used up, so why waste time on a release that's almost EOSS (*end of standard support*)  Also you didn't mention which 18.04 product you installed; if you installed the 2018-April GA kernel stack, or a later kernel HWE kernel stack (*the kernel stack being determined by product/ISO you didn't specify*)

Comment: @guiverc According to the official [Time to prepare for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS End of Standard Support on May 31, 2023](https://ubuntu.com/blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support) webpage Ubuntu 18.04 will reach the end of the standard, five-year maintenance window for Long-Term Support (LTS) releases on May 31, 2023. Please review your recent comments about 18.04 new questions.

Comment: @karel I realize that; I PM'd & spoke with Lech (*author of blog*) to confirm for Ubuntu News purposes (*days after the blog*) and got confirmation & reason for change. Upgraded packages will continue until 31-May-2023 as per the blog, but support as evidenced in `ubuntu-support-status` etc. still says April-2023 & I was told won't change. thus I've avoided an actual date & mention only *days* or the *five years of standard* support which hasn't been changed.  I see the extra *month* of support as a free *bonus* giving existing users more time to upgrade, but new installations are still unwise

Comment: Just to confirm the 18.04 EOL date, what do you think we should do? Should we go with Lech's blog for existing 18.04 users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)